# document.getElementById not working on cycle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I show you a script that is driving me crazy:

```
var nzone = localStorage.getItem("nzone");
var nrighe = localStorage.getItem("nrighe");
var nomoldzona = "x";

for (i=1; i<nrighe+1; i++) {
    var rigax = localStorage.getItem("riga"+i);

    var postzona = rigax.search("zona_");
    var nomzona = rigax.substr(postzona+7,postzona+9);
    //recupero il nome della zona
    var postaglio = rigax.search("kk");
    var str = rigax.substr(postaglio + 2);
    var postaglio2 = str.search("kk");

    var zona_nome = str.substr (0, postaglio2);

 // THIS IS THE PART GIVING ME TROUBLE
    if (nomzona != nomoldzona){
        var nzonen = nzonen+1;
        var nomoldzona = nomzona;

        //visualizzo zona in html

        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = document.getElementById('html').innerHTML;
        document.getElementById('spazio').appendChild(div);
        document.getElementById('zonetta').innerHTML=zona_nome;
    }
}
```

In this series I am going to create as many as there are div `nzonen` and up to far so good, but the last stage:

```
document.getElementById('zonetta').innerHTML=zona_nome;
```

When I go to replace the tag `<h3 id : " zonetta "> </h3>` The variable `zona_nome` it is only shown the first div, others remain empty. There is an error in the cycle?

Comment: An ID is unique on an HTML page. If you have more of one, the browser found only the first one of your html page.

Comment: You can use class attribute for multiple elements

Comment: `<h3 id : " zonetta ">` is not really valid html. Did you mean `<h3 id="zonetta">`?

Comment: <script id="html" language="text">
<a href="porte.html" class="portfolio-wide-item">
  <h1 id="zonetta"></h1>
  <p><span class="text-highlight highlight-dark">Temp. 23.05 C°</span><span class="text-highlight highlight-turqoise">Nessun allarme attivo</span></p>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <img class="responsive-image" src="images/pictures/1ww.jpg" alt="img">
  </a>
</script>

Answer (score 0):

It should be `<h3 id="zonetta"></h3>`. 
Your HTML tag is not valid and spaces are not trimmed in the ID name.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't clear and I couldn't write a comment on the question since I don't have 50 rep yet.